# bash : no such file or directory when adding gradle to path on linux

Tags: linux, bash, gradle, path, redhat

I created a local bin directory for user programs and edit my local `~/.bash_profile` to contain the following

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin:$HOME/bin/gradle-4.3/bin
```

I call the program `gradle` and I receive the following error:

> bash: /home/username/bin/gradle: No Such file or directory.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: tried `export "PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin:$HOME/bin/gradle-4.3/bin"` in terminal and it didn't work (with the `""`)?

Comment: Does /home/username/bin/gradle exist as a broken symbolic link or something similar?

Comment: @Dennis I know export works, but I want be able to call the program after closing the terminal.  there are no links added, 'gradle-4.3' Is a directory.

Comment: What does `type gradle` print?

Comment: Does `/home/username/bin/gradle` exist but you get `No such file or directory` when executing it? If so you have the wrong binary for your distro.

Comment: @GordonDavisson it prints  "bash: /home/username/bin/gradle: No Such file or directory" when I type gradle

Comment: @thatotherguy the directory 'gradle-4.3' I think it didn't recognize the minus sign for some reason when I call gradle.

Comment: "type" is part of the command string -- `type gradle` is the command "type", with "gradle" as an argument. It essentially asks the bash shell to tell you what it thinks the command `gradle` is. For example, `type echo` normally prints "echo is a shell builtin", and `type ls` prints something like "ls is hashed (/bin/ls)".

Answer (score 1):

Usually Paths in Linux/Mac are set using the `export`command. So you'd use:

`export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin:$HOME/bin/gradle-4.3/bin"`

Also after editing the .bash_profile you should source it to load the new PATH.

`source ~/.bash_profile` and if you want you can `echo $PATH` to see if it is correct.

Comment: Thanks! I call this and then log out and log back in!

Comment: Usually the .bash_profile gets sourced every time you start a new terminal. So if you have it in your .bash_profile, restart terminal program and you're good to go. I think.

Comment: Unless something is truly broken, `PATH` is already exported (as it was inherited from another process, or exported by a system configuration file before any user-configuration file is sourced. `export` should not be necessary.